Problema con Tomcat y Intellij
Muy buenas tardes a todos.
Estoy tratando de integrar Tomcat en la versión 10.1 a Intellij sin embargo me marca este problema:

/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java "-Dcatalina.home=/home/skynet/Proyectos JAVA/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-10.1.18" -Dcatalina.base=/home/skynet/.SmartTomcat/SpringWeb/SpringWeb -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/skynet/.SmartTomcat/SpringWeb/SpringWeb/temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/skynet/.SmartTomcat/SpringWeb/SpringWeb/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -javaagent:/snap/intellij-idea-community/498/lib/idea_rt.jar=41243:/snap/intellij-idea-community/498/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/home/skynet/Proyectos JAVA/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-10.1.18/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/skynet/Proyectos JAVA/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-10.1.18/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start.
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED.

Éste mismo servidor lo incorporo con NetBeans y no presenta ningún inconveniente.
¿Cuál es el problema con Intellij?
Gracias a todos.

muy buenas tardes; ¿Este problema te marca algun tipo de error más alla de la noota que estas agregando opciones a tu JDK y que te marca ALL_UNNAMED; ¿tienes permisos suficientes para esos modulos? Si fuera posible que al momento de ejecutar tu IDE obtuvieras un log de salida, si se queda trabado es que esta "esperando" por algo o "no encuentra algo" y es posible que sea desde un problema de path hasta uno de lectura. Quedo en espera de tu respuesta para pdoer buscar una causa raiz.

Gracias por la respuesta. Sí, tengo permisos suficientes. No obstante se abren dos consolas, TomCat Localhost Log y Tomcast Access Log, esperando a que ingrese caracteres, sin embargo nada. Ahora, también me aparece este mensaje: la biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib].
